# Creating a Data Cube from point measurements using ODC

Tags: open-data-cube

I wonder if Open Data Cube software can also handle point measurements (none-raster information). I am interested to create a data cube for CYGNSS satellite data. Each CYGNSS data file (in netCDF format) include daily point measurements (more than 8500 samples) from different locations. https://podaac.jpl.nasa.gov/dataset/CYGNSS_L1_V2.1
Is it possible to use ODC to resample CYGNSS data to a regular grid (netCDF format optimized in time direction)?